# How to debug Spring Boot Handler Mapping issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I just took over a code base that is a SpringMVC base project, its REST endpoints are not working

```
@RestController
public class RequestWeb {

    ....

    @PostMapping("/requests/v2")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<?> postRequestV2( //...
            @RequestHeader(HEADER_FEATURES) String features, //...
            @RequestBody requestBody requestBody //...

    ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The rest controller related annotation etc all look correct to me.
the main Application uses `@SpringBootApplication`, `@ComponentScan` has the right `basePackages` specifed.

I looked at `ComponentScanAnnotationParser`, `RestController` bean above was registered.

When I added a break point at the `initHandlerMappings` in the `DispatcherServlet` class, there are only three matching beans, which looked wrong.

[image: Wrong mapping results]

compared with my other good Spring MVC project,  I can see the `requestMappingHandlerMapping` is missing from results.

[image: correct results]

I don't know why `@PostMapping` did not work (it should have changed the bean type to `requestMappingHandlerMapping`?), where should I put a break point in the Spring Framework to debug this issue?

Comment: can you check whether @EnableWebMvc  added in your project?

Comment: Looks like youa re looking at the wrong `DispatcherServlet`. I suspect there are 2 in your application due to having spring-boot-actuator on the classpath and running on a different port. Also what isn't working that isn't clear to me from the question, finally the `@Produces` and `@Consumes` aren't Spring annotations but rather JAX-RS annotations and are ignored by Spring.

Comment: You should add --debug part of run configuration and look for bean which get registered or not. Sometimes different bean get registered part of auto configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum. There is only one DispatchServlet I believe, the breakpoint got hit. The project has SpringMVC and some Jersey stuff mixed together but it could work fine

Comment: @akreddy.21 Spring Boot adds it automatically when it sees spring-webmvc on the classpath. the fact DispatcherServlet is called means it is enabled

Comment: @NirajJha I enabled debug but did not find much useful info in the logs regarding the HandlerMapping scanning

Comment: Please add your pom/dependencies to your question as well as some configuration.